# Attribute action in form tag doesn't find my ActionResult

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have an mvc3 application and I'm trying to implement Forms Authentication. I'm trying to invoke the CheckUser ActionResult in my SecurityController controller but it just doesn't find it. I guess it searches in views folder. Any ideas? Here is the html code and yes, the action is called CheckedUser.

```
<form action="Security/CheckUser" method="post">
    Username:<br />
    <input type="text" name="usernametb" /><br />
    Password:<br />
    <input type="password" name="passwordtb" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" va``lue="Log In" />
</form>
```

Comment: ??? why do you post a form (view) ... the question is, what does your "router" with a request Security/CheckUser ... without code no solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form action="/Security/CheckUser" method="post">
```

in place of:

```
<form action="Security/CheckUser" method="post">
```